# phpMySQL how to select between some value

Tags: mysql, sql

I was create scoreboard for my game
But I wondering how to get a scores
only between my score

such as

if I have score 50,
and my scoreboard have a rows like this

1. Player Name 100
2. Player Name 80
3. Player Name 75
4. My Name 50 <<--- this is my score
5. Player Name 40
6. Player Name 30
7. Player Name 20
8. Player Name 10
9. Player Name 5
10. Player Name 0

SO, I really want to fetch only index between 2. to 7.
because their scores are between my score
and more than and less than my score, just about 2 index.

there are possible or have anyway?

Thanks!!!

Fetch a values between 2 values

Comment: "Between my score" - what does that mean? If the score is 50, there's nothing between 50

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * name, score FROM scores WHERE score > :myscore - 30 AND score < :myscore + 30;
```

That basic format should work, though you will of course have to adapt it to your situation.